# Configure NuGet package to add a build event when installed

Tags: nuget-package, build-events

Does anyone know if it's possible to add something to a nuspec file so that when a package is installed via NuGet a pre or post build event to a project?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think editing the user's PostBuildEvent property is the wrong way to go about adding a post-build action to a project. I believe the recommended way is to put your custom action into an MSBuild Target that is imported into the project file. As of [NuGet 2.5](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5), if you include a 'build' folder in your package (at the same level as content and tools) and it contains a {packageid}.targets file or {packageid}.props file, NuGet will automatically add an Import to the project file when you install the package.

For example you have a package called MyNuGet. You create a file build\MyNuGet.targets containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="MyNuGetCustomTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Message from MyNuGetCustomTarget. Configuration: $(Configuration)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This creates a custom target that is configured to run after the standard Build target. NuGet will handle inserting the Import on install and removing it on uninstall.

Comment: didn't see the entry added to the project after the install but they are getting called. NICE TY

Answer (score 9):

This is a slightly cleaner way to set a build event from an install.ps1 powershell script in the NuGet Package:

```
$project.Properties.Item("PostBuildEvent").Value = "your build event here"
```

Comment: can u help me solve this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840375/how-to-add-prebuildevent-in-install-ps1-in-nuget

Answer (score 6):

Not to the .nuspec file itself, but you can to `install.ps1` which you can add to your package using nuspec. Here is what I'm doing (I don't know if it's the best way to do it but it does work):

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$project.Properties | where { $_.Name -eq "PreBuildEvent" } | foreach { $_.Value = "copy `"`n`$(ProjectDir)Web.`$(ConfigurationName).config`" `"`$(ProjectDir)Web.config`"" }
```

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll try it out!

Comment: can u help me solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840375/how-to-add-prebuildevent-in-install-ps1-in-nuget