# $project.Properties is null in Init.ps1 (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I created a simple NuGet package that includes an Init.ps1 script in the Tools folder. The script starts as follows:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$postBuildEvent = $project.Properties.Item("PostBuildEvent").Value
```

When installing the package in a Visual Studio 2012 project I get an error on $project.Properties.Item, because $project.Properties is null: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression". I checked if $project.Properties is null and it is.

Question is, why it is null. I just try to alter the post build event (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290860/configure-nuget-package-to-add-a-build-event-when-installed)). Does anyone have clues?

**Edit:**
If the code is inside Install.ps1 it works. It seems that the project properties are not available when first installing a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter list for init.ps1 is:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package)
```

init.ps1 does not have the $project parameter because it is executed at the solution level and is not dependent on project.

See here for more information: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package